# How do I access update.php using nginx?

Tags: 8

I would like to use Drupal 8 (beta) with nginx. It works correctly, except update.php. It doesn't find it.

After analysing .htaccess (which is not processed by nginx) I realized that there is no real update.php file; it is served by index.php.

Does anyone have a working nginx configuration (with php5-fpm) which works with Drupal 8 beta, and that makes also update.php work?

Comment: Have tried  https://gist.github.com/JediSange/8742644 ?

Comment: Yes, a tried - it doesn't solve the update.php problem.

Comment: I would like to escalate this one, we are also on a nginx-setup and the updates are painful as we have to reinstall Drupal 8 from scratch between the betas. Anyone got any feedback here how to access the update.php-script using nginx?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This change worked for me
(Taken from https://www.drupal.org/node/2353907#comment-10567306)

```
location ~ ^/(index|update)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock; # might be different
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params; 
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Also see https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your nginx config file to rewrite 404 error to index.php

Just added this:

```
error_page 404 = @rewrite;
location @rewrite { 
  rewrite ^ /index.php;
}
```

Comment: I still get a 404 not found, could you elaborate this a little bit more?

Comment: @Undrium, do you use ISPConfig? If yes, you can unmark "Own Error-Documents" and insert my above code in options/"nginx Directives".
If not, you need to edit /etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/YourSite.vhost (in CentOS) adding my above code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the rewrite in your vhost for nginx. (nginx does not use .htacces and .htacces should be disabled in your config!

but here you go

```
    location ~ ^/(install|rebuild)\.php$ {
   # Are now present in the core location and need to be accesed directly so rewriting them. -- Lawri van Buël               
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /core$uri last;
        break;
    }
}
```

I have tested it in a broken D8 (It had some module error) but tested the rewrite parts using nginx and its debug log.

-- Removed update as I could not find it in the latest beta (I build it against an old version of d8 I now realize)

Comment: There is no update.php in my core folder, it's handled by the index.php routing these days I think.

Comment: its a 1 to 1 rewrite of the rules in the .htaccess from drupal 8 concerning these 3 mechanisms (there part of the same set) it does not matter if index.php handles it, since the default @rewrite rule would than trigger after the call to update.php , but with the correct path "/core/update.php" (this propably activates special meaning in the index.php if that is really the one handeling it)

Comment: This is where I lose you, guys, I cannot fully grasp how to get my setup using the update functionality. While index.php may take care of the update-process I cannot understand how to get it to work. Rewriting /update.php to go to index.php doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Undrium, you can gain more information of the rewrite mechanism using the nginx errorlog debug flag. (" errorlog <file> debug; ")

what you see there is that first is the rule found (or it should be first found at least) with '^/install.php' this is then rewritten to /core/index.php' next this is processed as if its a new request, the proces than does it again, until it resolves into a specific file to serve.

Answer (score 0):

The change matters to Nginx config is that Drupal 7 update.php URL is like

```
/update.php?op=info or /update.php?op=selection
```

while Drupal 8 update.php URL pattern is like

```
/update.php/selection or /update.php/result
```

So, what we need to change in the existing configuration is very simple. Look for your matching condition like

```
location ~ \.php$ {...}
```

then, change it to

```
location ~ \.php$|^/update.php {...}
```

For more details, please see my blog: https://insready.com/en/blog/update-your-nginx-config-support-drupal-8

Comment: I do not think, this is completely working config. You have to use `try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7` , if not, you can run into issues like [this](https://github.com/pantheon-systems/drops-8/issues/105)