# Can not remove the Devel module

Tags: 8

While doing an upgrade to the Devel-module something went terrible wrong. Decided to remove the module through the "Uninstall"-tab. The module is however not listed there, while it's marked as active under the "Install"-tab. Removing the module manually (deleting the files) causes errors so I cannot do it this way either.

Ironically I need this module to be able to re-install other modules which are outdated. Anyone got any feedback how to cleanly remove the Devel-module without the Uninstall tab?

I do not have Drush for D8, need another way as I got D6 and D7 instances installed on the same environment aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use the "normal" upgrade scenario for FTP servers?
(I usume this still works btw. haven't tested it on d8 yet)
 - Download your intended version of devel from d.o.
 - Unpack the download
 - Upload to the server in place of the old devel module (so same paths,permissions,etc)
 - Run the "update.php" script to update the Database.(you need to be admin to do this, or change your settings.php to temp. allow anyone to do it).
 - Devel should be updated now.

according to the docs this should work see [d.o. D8 Update a module](https://www.drupal.org/node/250790)

Comment: Cheers, mate for the reply but I cannot run the update.php script (another issue I have posted) since we are using nginx.

Comment: We use nginx as well, and we can use the update.php in d7 (I have not tested it in d8 yet) do you know what the reason is for nginx not allowing update.php to work?

Comment: Here's the thread I'm active in: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/136953/how-to-access-update-php-in-drupal-8-using-nginx

Comment: Drupal 8 not officially having an [upgrade path](https://www.drupal.org/node/2272713) yet doesn't mean that you can't try and play with upgrading from beta to beta or by chasing HEAD or use update.php. Of course, not for a production site.

Comment: I have written the needed rewrite rules on the thread you listed above ("How to access update.php in Drupal 8 using nginx?" Can you let me know if that solvees your issue?

Comment: I am not afraid of running the update-script, probably the opposite. :) Just having problem getting it to run on the D8-setup.

Answer (score 1):

Drush is the best solution IMHO.

You can install [Drush 7](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) is compatible with D6, D7 and D8.

You can too (dirty way):

1. Uninstall Drush 6 or that you have.
2. Install Drush 7.
3. Uninstall Devel Module (`drush pmu devel`)
4. Uninstall Drush 7.
5. Install Drush 6 or whatever again.

Comment: I'd rather not fiddle with Drush here, there must be some other way to remove it? The problem is that it is listed as active under the "Install"-tab.

Comment: its specificly said in the question that there is no drush available, so this could not beutilised than.